# constructor without arguments

Tags: java, netbeans, constructor, arguments

I have this class but I need to write it in a way that constructor (public StemmingAndLemmatization(TurkishMorphParser parser) ) has no arguments (public StemmingAndLemmatization()) ! how can I convert it?? any idea?

```
    public class StemmingAndLemmatization {
        TurkishMorphParser parser;

        public StemmingAndLemmatization(TurkishMorphParser parser) {
            this.parser = parser;
        }

        public void parse(String word) {
            System.out.println("Word = " + word);

            System.out.println("Parses: ");
            List<MorphParse> parses = parser.parse(word);
            for (MorphParse parse : parses) {
                System.out.println(parse.formatLong());
                System.out.println("\tStems = " + parse.getStems());
                System.out.println("\tLemmas = " + parse.getLemmas());
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            TurkishMorphParser parser = TurkishMorphParser.createWithDefaults();
            new StemmingAndLemmatization(parser).parse("kitabımızsa");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could adopt the builder pattern, or add a setter method.

Comment: In addition to the other suggestions, if it is going to be run under some dependency injection framework, you could have that inject an instance into your class, but the details would depend on the DI framework you're using.

Comment: I didnt know that I can use more than one constructor... I added an ampty constructor and it worked :) solved :)

Comment: thanks jgitter and david for answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to replace the functionality of your constructor with a method that will take in your parser, or you can have the constructor create its own parser.

```
public class StemmingAndLemmatization {
    TurkishMorphParser parser;

    public void setParser(TurkishMorphParser parser) {
       this.parser = parser;
    }
```

or

```
public StemmingAndLemmatization(TurkishMorphParser) {
     this.parser = TurkishMorphParser.createWithDefaults();
 }
```